# how to add the value of the next row within a group in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I get the RESULT Column?

```
P_Key   Staff   Amt EMI RESULT
372175  9174    1584    1   1584
372176  9174    1619    2   3203
372177  9174    1654    3   4857
372178  9174    1689    4   6546
372179  9174    1726    5   8272
699334  22057   1136    1   1136
699335  22057   1161    2   2297
699336  22057   1186    3   3483
699337  22057   1212    4   4695
699338  22057   1238    5   5933
699339  22057   1265    6   7198
699340  22057   1292    7   8490
699341  22057   1320    8   9810
699342  22057   1349    9   11159
```

Comment: do you need a sum of the column RESULT? please be more specific!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want a cumulative sum.  In SQL Server 2008, one method is `apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.result
from t cross apply
     (select sum(amt) as result
      from t2
      where t2.staff = t.staff and t2.emi <= t.emi
     ) t2;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. This will work in sql server 2012

```
select sum(Amt) over (partition by EMI order by EMI)as RESULT from Your_table
```

OR Try below

```
SELECT SUM(Amt) FROM Your_table a,
Your_table b
WHERE b.EMI <= a.EMI
GROUP BY a.EMI
ORDER BY a.EMI;
```

Comment: `sum() over (partition by [] order by [])` Applies to 2012 and above versions of `SQL Server`. the second table will not return the desired result

Comment: I already mention it in answer that it will works for sql server 2012

Comment: but he has tagged `sql server 2008`